# Do you know any proven UX training program designed for project managers?

Tags: training, project-management

A great product manager can direct a team to produce the best work and tune their teams to perform at their peak—and this is important. And now, it's as important to integrate UX tools and methods to improve product quality and process efficiency.

Do you know a proven training program designed for project manager?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking. Is it for a course for Product Manages to know what UX is about or how is it done(or how designs apply UX know-how to improve their designs)?

Comment: Training to gain the know-how to initiate, execute and lead UX projects.

Answer (score 1):

Actually no.  Most courses in my experience around User Experience are for people who want to learn or become proficient User Experience professionals.

A good way for a product manager to learn about User Experience is to be part of a group that receives in-house training at the company they work for.  This way they can get an overview and understanding without neccessarily getting into the details of user experience.

The Nielsen Norman Group offer such training via the link below.

http://www.nngroup.com/training/

Personally I believe product Managers should "know" their own role and stay within the realms of that, whilst having an overview understanding or other specialties.  If a project manager requires User Experience input, get a User Experience specialist involved.  If the company doesn't have one, consider employing one temporarily on contract (for the project only) or permanently.

I often see professionals in other roles try to assume a different role without much success.  In essense they get spread too thin and deliver poorly across the board instead of very well in their chosen area of expertise.

In short, a great product manager will see the value of task and activity distribution instead of trying to do it all themselves.

Comment: You’re right, they just need an overview and understanding without getting into the details. But it’s important because their role is to decide where and when to make UX investments and trace the impact of those investments, I think they need to “know” what is UX.

Comment: Absolutely @BenoitMeunier.  "Know" but not "do". :-)